# Phonegap IOS video controls displayed on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova

Using phonegap, I've a video that autoplays on app load. The desired functionality is that it plays with all controls hidden (even when the user taps the screen no controls are displayed) so that the effect of an animation is given rather than a video.

This works on the iPad as desired but on the iPhone the video controls are displayed by default and show/hide on tap.

I've achieved the autoplay and hidden controls on iPad by playing the video in a webview with the code below.

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = [enableViewportScale boolValue];
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I had to add webkit-playsinline to the video tag like below

```
<video src="video/login_animation.m4v" autoplay="false" preload="auto" webkit-playsinline></video>
```

and also specify to allow inline media playback to the UIWebView by adding the following:

```
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

It now plays exactly the same as on the iPad.